# Display all the subcategories from a specific category?

Tags: terms

I need to show all subcategories using

```
$product_category = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
```

actually I use:

```
<?php 

global $post;

$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat', 'hide_empty=0'  );
foreach ( $terms as $term ){
    $category_id = $term->term_id;
    $category_name = $term->name;
    $category_slug = $term->slug;

    echo '<li><a href="'. get_term_link($term->slug, 'product_cat') .'">'.$category_name.'</a></li>';
}   

?>
```

It's ok but it shows only the parent category and only one subcategory...

How to fix that?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try something like this:

#### by ID

```
function woocommerce_subcats_from_parentcat_by_ID($parent_cat_ID) {
    $args = array(
       'hierarchical' => 1,
       'show_option_none' => '',
       'hide_empty' => 0,
       'parent' => $parent_cat_ID,
       'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'
    );
  $subcats = get_categories($args);
    echo '<ul class="wooc_sclist">';
      foreach ($subcats as $sc) {
        $link = get_term_link( $sc->slug, $sc->taxonomy );
          echo '<li><a href="'. $link .'">'.$sc->name.'</a></li>';
      }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

#### by NAME

```
function woocommerce_subcats_from_parentcat_by_NAME($parent_cat_NAME) {
  $IDbyNAME = get_term_by('name', $parent_cat_NAME, 'product_cat');
  $product_cat_ID = $IDbyNAME->term_id;
    $args = array(
       'hierarchical' => 1,
       'show_option_none' => '',
       'hide_empty' => 0,
       'parent' => $product_cat_ID,
       'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'
    );
  $subcats = get_categories($args);
    echo '<ul class="wooc_sclist">';
      foreach ($subcats as $sc) {
        $link = get_term_link( $sc->slug, $sc->taxonomy );
          echo '<li><a href="'. $link .'">'.$sc->name.'</a></li>';
      }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

[Source/inspiration](https://github.com/darkdelphin/WooCommerce-Subcategories-widget/blob/master/woocommerce-subcategories-widget.php)

**Edit:**

Completed the code, tested it, see comments

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how to put that code into mine, anyway I found this code :

[http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73795/how-to-split-the-categories-of-subcategories-with-thumbnails]

but it shows All categories, I need just One category selected with its subcategories

Comment: Thanks my friend, I copied and pasted it in my woocommerce-template.php in the part where I need it to use, but it displays all the categories and none subcategories; please take a look at the link I posted above, it should be like that but with only one category and its subcategories

Comment: I took a quick look at the code from the questions you linked. What you are lloking to do is only do whats associated to `$sub_cats = get_categories( $args2 )` and the `$args2 = array( ... )` part, but that said, what i suggested is pretty much the same. So I'm not really sure why it isn't working for you.

Comment: if I remove `function woocommerce_subcats_from_parentcat($parent_cat) {`
it works, but shows only main categories, not subcategories, if I copy and paste your code as it is, it shows blank, none.

Comment: Ok, it shows subcategories and not main category, but only if I put '23', with '21' it's all blank.. 
thanks for your help, if you could fix this last little bug it would be great for me

Comment: ok it works, i need just to show the main category above the subcategories:
MAIN CATEGORY
  - sub cat
  - sub cat

Comment: ok, my friend, everything works fine! thanks a lot!!
just a small question:
is it possible to show always the main category when I click on a subcategory?

Comment: it certainly is possible, but it seems like a question to me, ask it properly; this might help you: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56784/get-main-parent-categories-for-a-product

Comment: yes probably is the best solution, but how can i call these two functions in my page?

Comment: anyway, the problem still remains:
woocommerce_subcats_from_parentcat_by_ID($parent_cat_ID) displays only sub categories, and woocommerce_subcats_from_parentcat_by_NAME($parent_cat_NAME) displays only ALL main categories with no sub.

Comment: I need MAIN->sub and once i click on sub it should be the same as parent 'MAIN->sub'. I need that this kind of menu doesn't change if I clik on MAIN or a sub

Comment: First of all, both functions are working perfectly fine for me, you are maybe using one of them wrong. Secondly, you should be able to achieve the wanted behaviour with the information here and on the question linked above. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for this :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code that worked for me in a page template (my parent id was 7):

```
<?php $wcatTerms = get_terms('product_cat', array('hide_empty' => 0, 'orderby' => 'ASC', 'parent' => 7, )); 
        foreach($wcatTerms as $wcatTerm) : 
        $wthumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $wcatTerm->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
        $wimage = wp_get_attachment_url( $wthumbnail_id );
    ?>
    <div><a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $wcatTerm->slug, $wcatTerm->taxonomy ); ?>">
    <?php if($wimage!=""):?><img src="<?php echo $wimage?>" class="aligncenter"><?php endif;?></a>
    <h3 class="text-center"><a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $wcatTerm->slug, $wcatTerm->taxonomy ); ?>"><?php echo $wcatTerm->name; ?></a></h3>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: A simpler form of @mikes's answer without the image option - can replace lines 6-10 with: <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $wcatTerm->slug, $wcatTerm->taxonomy ); ?>"><?php echo $wcatTerm->name; ?></a>