# How can I list only Subcategories in Woocommerce

Tags: php, plugins, e-commerce

So I have been able to list all the categories in woocommerce, but I am having trouble trying to list the subcategories of the category 'bathrooms'.

Does anyone have any idea how I can achieve this?

here is the code I am currently using...

```
<?php $tax_terms = get_terms('product_cat', 'hide_empty=0' ); ?>
        <ul>
          <?php foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
            echo '<li>' . '<a href="' . esc_attr(get_term_link($tax_term, $taxonomy)) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "%s" ), $tax_term->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $tax_term->name.'</a></li>';
    } ?>
```

Comment: Does http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/101268/woocommerce-how-can-i-show-all-the-subcategories-from-a-specific-category answer your question?

Comment: Tried that but it doesn't work. It lists the 4 main categories for me... but I want to lis the sub categories of the main category called 'bathrooms'.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```
$args = array(
     'parent' => 100, // id of the direct parent
     'hide_empty' => false,
);

$cats = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );

foreach( $cats as $cat ) {
  // do your loop stuff here
}
```

[Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) is more information on this function and additional arguments you can use.